# Imagemap works only in IE

Tags: html, css, imagemap

I assume its because of positioning, padding and margins. But I really cant fit this `imagemap` right on element menu. Only IE shows it in good way: http://xn--wiadomesny-37b.pl/bg/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"l lang="pl">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>{TITLE}</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="{H1}" />
<meta name="description" content="{DESC}" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="outer_wrapper">
  <div class="content_bg">

    <div class="wrapper"><div class="promo"><img src="images/header.png" width="655" height="238" /></div>
      <div class="menu"><img src="images/menu.png" width="601" height="158" usemap="#Map" />
        <map name="Map" id="Map">
          <area shape="circle" coords="66,86,64" href="#" alt="" />
          <area shape="circle" coords="217,68,68" href="#" alt="" />
          <area shape="circle" coords="371,69,64" href="#" alt="" />
          <area shape="circle" coords="529,88,67" href="#" alt="" />
        </map>
      </div>
      <div class="content"><div class="content_text">{CONTENT}</div></div>
      <div class="sider">
        <div class="sider_top"></div>
        <div class="sider_bg">{SIDEBAR}</div>
        <div class="sider_bottom"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer_left">{FOOTER}</div>
        <div class="footer_right"><strong>Wykonanie</strong>: <a href="http://www.firmowa-strona-www.pl" title="Tanie strony www firmowe">Firmowa Strona WWW</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is being caused by the `z-index` in this rule:

```
.content_bg {
    background-image: url("../images/bg_overlay.png");
    background-position: center 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 814px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 40px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -20; /* remove this line */
}
```

Comment: @Ultra: First of all the rule doesn't seem to be needed at all and the site works perfect without it. But the reason it messes up, is because you have effectively sent everything behind `.outer_wrapper`. You can test this by adding this rule `.outer_wrapper {background: #000;}` and you will see everything disappears.

Comment: Oh so I was clicking .outer_wrapper. Its so begginers mistake. Learning every day, thank you.